# Passing a TStringList by reference/pointer to a function

Tags: c++builder

I'm rather new at this, but I need to create a `TStringList` in one function, pass it to another function to modify it, then use the results back in the first function. However, everything I try reports an error:

> No matching function call.

Calling function:

```
std::unique_ptr<TStringList>metaData(new TStringList());
...
_retVal = ParseOMT(inpBuf, &metaData, _reportIt);
...
```

ParseOMT.h:

```
bool ParseOMT(const String ABuffer, TStringList* _currMetadata, String &_reportIt);
```

ParseOMT.cpp

```
bool ParseOMT(const String ABuffer, TStringList* _metadata, String &_reportIt) {
```

I have tried various combinations of the `*` and `&` in the `ParseOMT()` declaration and calling function, to no avail.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ParseOMT()` function as shown is fine.  The code that is calling it is wrong.

[`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has a [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) method which returns the object pointer being held.

So, simply change this:

```cpp
_retVal = ParseOMT(inpBuf, &metaData, _reportIt);
```

To this instead:

```cpp
_retVal = ParseOMT(inpBuf, metaData.get(), _reportIt);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I have seen you around for a long time. Glad to see you are still with us.

Comment: Would I have to do the `.get()` is I changed the `std::unique_ptr` to `auto TStringList *metaData = new TStringList();`?

Comment: @JKofsky `auto TStringList *metaData` won't compile. You need to drop either the `auto` or the `TStringList`. But no, raw pointers don't have methods, so just pass `metaData` as-is since it is the type of raw pointer that `ParseOMT()` is expecting, eg: `_retVal = ParseOMT(inpBuf, metaData,_reportIt);`